# Why does a JavaScript array item created via dot notation exist but not get counted in array.length?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Although counterintuitive, it *is* possible to create a JavaScript array "property" using dot notation:

```js
const arr = [];

arr.dot = "notation";

console.log(arr.dot); // "notation"
```

Weird, but ok. However, the array's length still registers as 0:

```js
const arr = [];

arr.dot = "notation";

console.log(arr.dot); // "notation"

console.log(arr.length); // 0
```

Two questions:

1. Why is the array's length not impacted by the property assigned via dot notation?
2. Why is it possible to assign a property to an array via dot notation?

Comment: JavaScript is weird.

Comment: arrays are exotic objects. (literately)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A JavaScript array is just an object. You're setting the property `dot` on the object.

You can confirm that an array is an object by doing:

`typeof arr`.

The `length` property is computed based on the number of numeric entries in the array.

Here's an excerpt taken from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

> Arrays cannot use strings as element indexes (as in an associative array) but must use integers. Setting or accessing via non-integers using bracket notation (or dot notation) will not set or retrieve an element from the array list itself, but will set or access a variable associated with that array's object property collection. The array's object properties and list of array elements are separate, and the array's traversal and mutation operations cannot be applied to these named properties.

Answer (score 1):

That dot notation is actually assigning a property to the array, not pushing a new value!

```js
const myArray = ['apples', 'bananas'];
console.log(myArray);
myArray[2] = 'peach';
console.log(myArray);
```

I assume this is what made you look towards objects, which do this for assignment:

```js
const myObject = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Pig',
  type: 'animal',
}

// Standard dot-notation assignment
myObject.sound = 'Oink!';
console.log(myObject);
// "Computed" assignment
myObject['emoji'] = '';
console.log(myObject);
```

Here's a good read on the topic above https://ui.dev/computed-property-names/.

Back to the question at hand, though: why can't I do this:

```js
const myArray = ['choclate', 'strawberry'];
myArray.pinapple = 'Tasty';
```

Arrays are essentially lists. It doesn't make sense to add an attribute (i.e. "describer") to a list.

Don't get me wrong - it is perfectly alright to set properties of an Array (as it is based off JavaScript objects), but it isn't used in the way that you're thinking of.

Here's an example of when I might use the "dot notation" assignment for an Array:

```js
let zoo = ['Dolphin', 'Lion', 'Monkey'];
console.log(zoo);
// In-built property
console.log('I have', zoo.length, 'animals in my zoo!');
// Now, let's add a property "income"
zoo.income = 500;
console.log('My zoo has £%s', zoo.income);
// We can use this like a normal object property
zoo.income += 50;
console.log('My zoo has £%s', zoo.income);
// Let's create a method for when the zoo goes out of business
zoo.closeDown = () => {
  zoo = [];
  zoo.income = 0;
  return true;
}
zoo.closeDown();
console.log(zoo);
console.log('My zoo has £%s', zoo.income);
```

Why would I want to do this? In this example, I could've used an object. But it's possible that it makes more sense to keep the animals in my zoo as an array, and then build up the methods and properties from there.

Okay, but how do I get a list of these properties/methods then?

```js
const myArray = ['Foo', 'Bar'];
myArray.isCool = true;
console.log(myArray);
console.log(myArray.length);
let i;
for (i in myArray) {
  console.log(i, myArray[i]);
}
```

The `for (i in ...)` syntax can be used here, as we are iterating through the properties of the array **as an object**. As we know from before, **Arrays extend the Object class** (kind of).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

1. `length` only counts the numeric properties.
2. Arrays are objects, so you can add other properties to them.

You don't even have to use dot notation, you can write `arr["dot"] = "notation";`